# Solving a recurrence relation formula with squared

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

I hope someone can help me with that:
$$T(n)=T(2^{\sqrt{\log n}})+1$$

I will be asked to answer what is the runtime complexity of the algorithm.
I tried to set m=2^ and still failed.

Comment: What algorithm? I see no algorithm in your question.

Comment: Which logarithm base ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming base-$2$ logarithms, we set

$$n=2^{2^{2^m}}$$ and transform

$$T\left(2^{2^{2^m}}\right)=\\
T\left(2^{\sqrt{\log\left(2^{2^{2^m}}\right)}}\right)+1
=T\left(2^{\sqrt{{2^{2^m}}}}\right)+1
=T\left(2^{2^{\left(2^m\right)}/2}\right)+1
=T\left(2^{2^{2^{m-1}}}\right)+1
.$$

This is of the form

$$S(m)=S(m-1)+1$$ and has the simple solution

$$S(m)=S_0+m.$$

Hence,

$$T(n)=T_4+\log(\log(\log(n))).$$

Comment: Can you explain the transition to S(m) Please

Comment: @Bubi: $S(m)=T\left(2^{2^{2^m}}\right)$.